# Add a correct format date in Excel file with Python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

I need to add a new line from a dict Dict to excel file, and into this Dict i have a date value but this one was added like a text format in the cell f excel file

this is my code to do that, the probleme is with datetime.fromisoformat(row['Date']).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") but it was added with text format in excel file

```
Declaration_dict = Excel_Dict(r"\\path_to_excel_file.xlsx")
    for row in Declaration_dict:
        if row['statut'] == 'OK':
            line_declaration = (row['Cle_modifiee'], row['via'], row['Reference'], datetime.fromisoformat(row['Date']).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), row['Detail'], row['NOM'], row['User'], row['Metier'], row['Equipe'], row['Libelle'])
            sheet_stock.append(line_declaration)
```

Comment: Dates in Excel are binary values, they have no format. They're displayed using the cell style and the end user's locale settings. Use a Python `datetime` instead of trying to guess the cell's style or the end user's locale

Comment: That `.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")` almost always a bug. While some applications can handle the unambiguous ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD), there's no way to say whether 4/7/2023 is April 7th or July 4th

Comment: Besides, the code you posted doesn't try to "add" a format. It correctly reads the Excel date before converting it to a localized string. Use just `datetime.fromisoformat(row['Date'])` if not `row['Date']` alone. If the Excel sheet contains actual dates, `row['Date']` will return them as `datetime` values.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i had the same probleme, the Cell is with standard format not Date

Answer (score 0):

i use just **datetime.fromisoformat(row['Date'])** but i didn't have a cell with date format, the cell is with Standard format

[excel file result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJLXn.jpg)